# Why do I get a not declared in this scope error even though the header file is included?

Tags: c++

The error I get is

```
/opt/workspace/IhmActon/ihm_acton/src/model_inference/retinanet/engine.cpp:213:5:
error: ‘trt_unique_ptr’ was not declared in this scope
     trt_unique_ptr<trt::IHostMemory> serialized_engine = wrap_trt_ptr(engine->serialize());
```

This is a photo snippet of that function and where the error is  [image]

The declaration of trt_unique_ptr is in this header file(tensorrt.hpp). [image]

In engine.hpp, I have an import statement to include that header file - `#include "model_optimizer/tensorrt.hpp"` . I do not see any errors with the import statement

Why do I still get this not declared in scope error?

Comment: `trt_unique_ptr` is inside namespace `ihm_springfield`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trt_unique_ptr` is inside namespace `ihm_springfield`. Use `ihm_springfield::trt_unique_ptr` instead.